# How to keep `textarea` expanded when focused on parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a textarea box that expands when clicked, and retracts when it's not focused.

However, if the textbox is already in expanded form, I want it to remain in expanded form if the user clicks anywhere in the *container* area (The blue area in the snippet).

Here is my CSS for animating the *textarea*

```css
.container {
  width: 588px;
  background: #E8F5FD;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
  opacity: 1.00;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

textarea {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  width:508px;
  height:38px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 100%;
  opacity: 1.00;
  border: 1px solid #C6E7FB;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: all 0.0s ease;
  resize: none;
}

textarea:focus {
  width: 508px;
  height: 82px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  
<textarea> </textarea>

  <button
type="button"
className="sendButton"
onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Send</button>
  
</div>
```

How can I keep the textbox in expanded form if the user clicks anywhere in the *container* div? And have it behave as it does now if the user clicks anywhere outside of the *container*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular block elements like `div` tags are not, by default, focusable. However, you can make any element focusable by adding the attribute `tabindex="-1"`, at which point you can use CSS to expand the `textarea` when either `.container` is focused *or* the `textarea` is focused. This method is performant, too, as it requires no JavaScript!

```css
.container:focus textarea,
textarea:focus {
  width: 508px;
  height: 82px;
}

.container {
  width: 588px;
  background: #E8F5FD;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
  opacity: 1.00;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

textarea {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 508px;
  height: 38px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 100%;
  opacity: 1.00;
  border: 1px solid #C6E7FB;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: all 0.0s ease;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" tabindex="-1">
  <textarea> </textarea>
  <button type="button" className="sendButton" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow... living and learning, didn't know this about `tabindex`! amazing!

Comment: Yeah . . . there was a lot about accessibility attributes I didn't know until I started watching [A11yCasts with Rob Dodson](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNYkxOF6rcICWx0C9LVWWVqvHlYJyqw7g) (from the Google Chrome Developers team).

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be solved in two parts by modifying your HTML and using a little CSS.

The solution is to add a focus pseudo class to the div so that when the container is clicked on we can expand the size of the child textarea. Here's the code...

```
.container:focus textarea {
  width: 508px;
  height: 82px;
}
```

One issue remains and that is that by default you can't focus on a div element, so we'll have to add a tabindex attribute to the div in the HTML.

```
<div class = "container" tabindex="-1">
```

The `tabindex` attribute is used to add the element to the list of items which can be tabbed through using the keyboard. However, a value of -1 removes the ability to tab through the element in question.

Make sure you leave the original focus psuedo class that targets the textarea.

The only issue with this solution is that should the user click on the light blue area outside the textbox, the browser will show focus on the surrounding div. It's kind of ugly. I'd be interesting in hearing solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make browser understand the clicks & be able to respond them you need javascript's help & specially its event listening mechanism.

every user interaction to the page is an *event* that browser can *listen* & catch it. Then you (developer) can tell the browser what to do on detecting an event.

Here I just told the browser to make the `textarea` larger when user clicks in it (`focus event` to our `textarea`). & make it smaller whenever user clicks outside (`blur event` to our `textarea`). Technically speaking, I added 2 `eventlisteners` on `focus` & `blur` to the `<textarea>`(that now has `id="myArea"`).

here is the working snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("myArea").addEventListener('focus', function(){
    this.width = 508;
    this.height = 82;
});

document.getElementById("myArea").addEventListener('blur', function(){
    this.width = 508;
    this.height = 42;
});
```

```css
.container {
width: 588px;
background: #E8F5FD;
mix-blend-mode: normal;
opacity: 1.00;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 10px;
}

textarea {
font-family: "Roboto";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
width:508px;
height:38px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 100%;
opacity: 1.00;
border: 1px solid #C6E7FB;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-left: 5px;
transition: all 0.0s ease;
resize: none;
}

textarea:focus {
width: 508px;
height: 82px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  
<textarea id="myArea"> </textarea>

  <button
type="button"
className="sendButton"
onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Send</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: ? I didn't understand your answer

Comment: @andrepaulo In order to make browser understand the clicks & be able to respond to then you need javascript's help & specially its `event listening` mechanism. every user interaction to the page is an `event` that browser can `listen` & catch it. Then you (developer) can tell the browser what to do on detecting an event. Here I just said the browser to make the `textarea` larger when user clicks in it (`focus` event to our textarea). & make it smaller whenever user clicks outside (`blur` event to our text area)

Comment: you should add this explanation to your answer :)

Comment: @andrepaulo Good suggestion. Done it.